# PhpUnit - group exclusion settings from bootstrap.php

Tags: php, phpunit, bootstrapping

I currently have multiple test runners which only differs from each other in the working directory. All of them uses the same bootstrap.php which configures the class autoload. I recently added test group annotations to my tests and I exclude tests depending on PHP versions. Currently I add test runner options for example `--exclude-group closure-binding` under php 5.4, but for those I have to duplicate every test runner and set the options manually. I think it would be much better if I could add modifications to the bootstrap.php and setup the group exclusion from there. Is there a way to do that?

(phpunit version 3.7.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Sebastian](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1226), it is not possible, I have to use the [@requires annotation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests-using-requires) instead of that.

*note: The @requires annotation works well, but I always got parse error because of the usage of `yield` and `::class` in the lower versions... So I ended up not to care about this, however I'll keep the annotations. Maybe later I'll write a project which can automatically comment out test code depending on the annotation and the php version.*

For the case the code is not parsable by older php versions, yo have to move it to separate files, give them appropriate suffixes and set a configuration xml file like this:

```
    <testsuite name="unit tests">
        <directory suffix="Test.php" phpVersion="5.3.0" phpVersionOperator=">=">test/unit</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test54.php" phpVersion="5.4.0" phpVersionOperator=">=">test/unit</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test55.php" phpVersion="5.5.0" phpVersionOperator=">=">test/unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that on your bootstrap.php but you can use different XML configuration files, with distinct group configurations (example copied from the [docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.groups)):

```
File: closure-binding.xml

<groups>
  <include>
    <group>whatever</group>
  </include>
  <exclude>
    <group>closure-binding</group>
  </exclude>
</groups>

phpunit -c closure-binding.xml
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Nope this is not PHP version dependent configuration... It should be something like this: `if (php version < 5.4) then exclude(closure-binding);`.

Comment: Thinking about it, the XML solution is just an alias of passing --exclude-group params to the phpunit command, so even if it is more convenient, it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Ye, I have to reconfigure phpunit groups somehow from the bootstrap file. Another option to write a bash script to set the exclude groups dependent on the php version, but I don't know whether it would be compatible with my IDE...